# find a line with a string and replace entire line with another line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, find

I want to search a file with name file.txt in a directory and replace entire line in those files with a string `aprun` by another line `vasprun = "mpirun -np 64 vasp"`
How can I do this with awk or sed or any other bash utility?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU bash and GNU sed:

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i 's/.*aprun.*/vasprun = "mpirun -np 64 vasp"/' -- **/file.txt
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`:
>                         If  set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories
>                         match.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the file using the find command and pipe the output to sed command

`find . -name file.txt | sed -i 's/.*aprun.*/vasprun = "mpirun -np 64 vasp"/g'`