# replace entire line in file with new line given arguments line number and replacement string with special characters

Tags: bash, sed

I have 2 bash script variables defined:

```sh
THELINENUMBER="14" # an arbitrary line number, comes from a separate command
NEWLINE="a line/ with@ special! characters<" # arbitrary line with special characters, comes from separate command
```

I need to use the line number `${THELINENUMBER}` to replace a line in a file called `after.txt` with `${NEWLINE}`.
How do I do that?
These are some examples I have tried:

```
sed -i '${THELINENUMBER}s#.*#"/"${NEWLINE}"/"' after.txt
sed -i "${THELINENUMBER}s#.*#"/"${NEWLINE}"/"" after.txt
sed -i "${THELINENUMBER}s/.*/'${NEWLINE}'" after.txt
sed -i '${THELINENUMBER}s,.*,${NEWLINE}' after.txt
```

I am told that the delimitter is usually a `/`, but those are present in my line replacement variable, so I can't use those. I tried with `#` and `,` but the desired behavior did not change. I am also told that `"` and `'` are supposed to be used to turn off escaping in text (use literal string), but I have not been able to get that to work either. How do I pass in a string parameter into `sed` that has special characters? I am wondering if I should pass the variable `${NEWLINE}` into another built-in function call to add escape characters or something before passing it into `sed`. Is `sed` the right tool for the job? I did not find much helpful information looking at the CLI manpages. I use Ubuntu 18.04.

I have referred to these sources in my internet search:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file-by-line-number
https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372047/find-a-line-with-a-string-and-replace-entire-line-with-another-line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i "${THELINENUMBER}s#.*#${NEWLINE}#" after.txt
```

this works because:

1. You require `"` enclosing the entire sed command instead of backtick so that the variables are expanded
2. No other quotes or backticks are needed to escape `"` in the variables as there aren't any: there are no literal (escaped) quotes inside the variables
3. An alternate separator (such as `#`) is required due to the `/` inside the `NEWLINE` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `c` (change) command.

By the way, the naming convention for regular shell variables is NOT ALLCAPS, as that may result in accidental collisions with special variables like `PATH`.

```
sed "$linenumber c\\
$newline" file
```

Comment: I tried the command, and it spits out the correct result to the terminal. I looked at the actual text file, and I don't see any changes to the file saved on disk. How do I make the change persistent to the file? I was using the operator `>` and the file would simply be wiped.

Comment: @robotsfoundme Add the `-i` option to tell `sed` to modify the original file "in-place".